# Dried bits of polyurethane in recently refinished floor?

Tags: hardwood-floor, polyurethane, hardwood-refinishing

Over the past few days I refinished the hardwood floors in my living/dining rooms. I sanded the floors with a Home Depot random orbital sander rental at the beginning of the week before applying a stain and 3 coats of oil-based polyurethane (Varathane Ultimate Polyurethane) over two days. It is looking great with the exception of a few spots I have seen on the floor where there are rough, dime to quarter-sized raised areas of poly. I think what happened is that polyurethane from the previous day dried in the paint tray and then stuck to the floors when I rolled on the third coat today.

[image: Bits of dried polyurethane seen on recently finished floors.]

Is there a good way to remove these? I am thinking I could sand them down until they become flush with the floor and then brush on a small coat of poly to the surrounding area, but I wouldn’t know what grit sandpaper to use or if applying poly in small areas like that will work at all. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Sand down and re-coat. Of course clean the paint tray:)

Comment: Probably want to use a few different grits of sandpaper.  Start rough then go down to fine or very fine.

Comment: Thanks! 

Solar Mike, how do I clean the tray? I tried paint thinner and it didn’t seem to do anything to help get the dried poly up. 

And it is okay to sand and recoat in a small area like that, rather than the whole room?

Comment: If it's already dried in the tray then throw the tray out and get a new one - that one's now ruined for any job where you care about the result. In future, clean the tray at the same time and with the same product you use to clean the roller (which is typically listed on the side of the can under 'Cleanup'.

Comment: Your best bet is to get a quality roller pan, then get the el-cheapo 99¢ pan liners that you can just throw away after every painting session. 100% avoids this problem in the future.

Comment: Should be okay with a new job.  If it had been months or years, then it would be different, would be hard to match new finish to the older, faded/worn finish.